# How to localize DataAnnotations

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, globalization, dataform

Adding a Display Attribute to a property then having the DataField automatically do its tooltip magic makes for a great demo.  But for those of us in multilingual countries how is that to be localized?

Comment: Thats one reason not to use attributes.. You'll have to implement it yourself, like always with resource files and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the DisplayAttribute has support for localization.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.resourcetype%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

For this attribute, you can set the `Name` property to be a resource key, and then set the `ResourceType` property to the type of your resources class.